# How to use plain 315 MHz RF Transmitter with Simple RF T4 Receiver - 315MHz using Raspberry Pi?

Tags: rf, raspberry-pi, prototyping

I bought a 315 MHz RF receiver - Simple RF T4 Receiver - 315MHz Toggle Type - and a transmitter - Keyfob Single Button RF Remote Control 315MHz, both from Adafruit.
After trying some prototyping to interface the transmitter with a Raspberry Pi, I think I damaged it. I'm now considering buying a plain transmitter - [RF Link Transmitter - 315MHz](http://www.zeroohm.ae/wireless/RF-Link/RF-Link-Transmitter-315MHz), but the documentation is for a different receiver and the code is written for Arduino. I'm a total newbie when it comes to prototyping, so I am in desperate need for help. It does not matter with the receiver what LED lights up, as long as one or more lights up, indicating a received signal.

Answer (score 1):

The 'Simple RF T4 Receiver' has an SC2272 decoder which accepts a 12 bit serial transmission protocol which was designed by Holtek (HT12 chipset). Normally this is generated by a matching encoder in the keyfob.

If you use a bare tx module without encoder then you have to generate the pulse trains directly. The Arduino 'virtual wire' library performs this function. Unfortunately it is written specifically for AVR MCUs and won't work on the Rasberry Pi. Therefore you have 3 options:-

1. Use some existing code for the PI that emulates an HT12e, PT2262 or SC2262 encoder (I couldn't find any in a quick Google search).
2. Port the Arduino Virtual Wire code over to the Pi. Trickest part will probably be doing the 62.50 ms timer interrupt.
3. Attach an HT12E or equivalent encoder IC to the tx module, and use the Pi's GPIO to 'push the buttons' on the encoder's inputs.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing quick response. I think that, to be on the safe side, I'm going to use serial communication between the Raspberry Pi and an Arduino and use the the second RF Link Transmitter with its appropriate receiver.

Comment: Also, if I wanted to use the Virtual Wire library with an Arduino, how would I make it work with the receiver I already have?

Comment: Virtual Wire library simply pulses a port pin with the correct high/low sequence at ~62.5ms intervals. To port it to the Pi you just need to modify the low level stuff (timer interrupt, GPIO pin). If you have an Arduino then use that instead!

Comment: What message do I send from the second receiver I bought to activate the first transmitter using the VW library?

Comment: The Simple RF T4 Receiver has 8 pads for setting the address bits, and accepts 4 data bits. The transmitter must send the matching 8 bit address code, then the 4 data bits. The bits are 3 level, sent in

Comment: I found this:-  http://www.mhr.me.uk/projects/socketcontrol.html